# react native can't assign simple variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the weirdest (i'm sure it's simple) bug with react native.

I am using `Parse` for the backend. getting a parse object and trying to render a react object from it's attributes. simple.

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
        console.log(rowData);
        var data = rowData._serverData;
        var photo_url = rowData._serverData.photo_url;
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.rowPressed(rowData.guid)}
                underlayColor='#dddddd'>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                        <Image style={styles.thumb} source={{ uri: photo_url }} />
                        <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{rowData._serverData.badge}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.description}
                                numberOfLines={2}>{rowData._serverData.description}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.separator}/>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
```

I'm getting `cannot read property 'photo_url' of undefined` for this row 
`var photo_url = rowData._serverData.photo_url;`. 
this thing is , the data is there, I have made sure with the chrome debugger.

[image: debugger screen shot]
[image: error screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

turns out there is something weird with `Parse`.
doing this:

`rowData.attributes.photo_url`

solved it. I have to say i'm not quite sure why.